# Request.IsAuthenticated throws NullReferenceException in controller base class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a custom controller class, and I use cookies to keep tracks of the users that flagged the 'remember me' checkbox.
But when I try to access `Request.IsAuthenticated`, to see if the user has the login ticket, it throws a `NullReferenceException`. Where am I wrong?

My code:

```
public class JekController : Controller
{
    ...
    public JekController()
        : base()
    {
        LoginService = new LoginService();
        TimeSheetService = new TimeSheetService();

        if(!Request.IsAuthenticated) //NullReferenceException: Request is null
        {
            LoginService.SignInFromAuthCookie(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you try `HttpContext.Current.Request`? The request property of the controller isn't set until the controller is created.

Comment: It gives me `'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found`

Comment: Why are you trying to access Request in a constructor?

Comment: Because I have to load the user model if the user has set the login cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you needed was `System.Web.HttpContext`

```
public JekController() : base()
{
    ...

    if(!System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        LoginService.SignInFromAuthCookie(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already said that this gives me `'System.Web.HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase' could be found`

Comment: It's supposed to be `System.Web.HttpContext` not `System.Web.HttpContextBase` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: You are completely right. I'm gonna upvote when my edit is accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved following this: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/18457/requestuser-object-is-null-in-controller-constructor-in-aspnet-mvc

You need to override the Initialize() method and check the session:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);

    if (requestContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```